# Can NODE.JS be included and implemented universally?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a quiz, and I've been wanting to save my answers to a text file. I want to use "Node.js", and I'm worried about this: They only offer an installer to install Node.js on your computer. Since I'm not working with servers or anything like that, and I'm just a hobbyist creating a Quiz interface because the one provided by my school is absolute garbage, so the people I might first give this to may not have Node.js installed on their computer. I'm using *node.js* for editing text documents and saving to them from my website. Please do note that this is for a **website, not a program.**

Is there any way I can include *node.js* source code in same directory as my website, or elsewhere, and use it from there, so that people without *node.js* can also use it without having to install anything?

Thanks for any help!

*This question was edited, because I hadn't asked a more clear question in the first place, and people thought I was using a server.(my mistake. Sorry!) I have edited this for people who are comfortable using a server or a hosting app.*

Comment: You can use Node to create websites using something like Koa or Express.

Comment: the node that you install is more or less a programming tool that you use for stuff like npm, where you can then add packages to your code and stuff like that. No one will need to have node installed on their computer to run anything.

Comment: I recommend you to google basic tutorials on node, javascript, html, css, some database like mongodb. Making a whole website is a pretty big task for someone who has never done anything like this - I would recommend you to do smaller stuff first.

Comment: @MauriceNino, I have made smaller stuff before. I'm using node to help with editing text files

Comment: @Keith, I'l definitely check those out.

Comment: Would be easier to judge if you told us what you wanted to do with it exactly. You can't use node for frontend development, so I don't know why the user should need to install it.

Comment: @MauriceNino  Node can be used front end too, that's basically what Electron is.  VS Code, for example is an Electron app.

Comment: @MauriceNino , I'm using node to edit and save text documents from a website.

Comment: So are you trying to distribute a Node.js application (and by application I mean anything that does something), without making anyone have to install node on their computers?

Comment: my bad - meant for website frontend @Keith

Comment: @WebsiteCreator I might be dumb, but I still don't get what you are trying to do

Comment: @MauriceNino, I have a website-in-development that takes quizzes, and after the quiz ends, I need to save the results to a text file, along with other information, like a "quiz done" mark that prevents users from attempting it twice. I want to use node as it seems like the most popular one out there, for these types of things.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes, Exactly. And everything without having to connect to the internet for testing it out.(except when it actually goes online)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ship standalone nodejs binary with your app. [node.exe](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/win-x64/node.exe) ([dist](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/win-x64/))

Then make your project and add your deps locally `npm i xxx` (without `g` flag)
And ship `node_modules` directory also.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have mentioned that this is not for an app, but for a website that is made to work on all platforms. Thanks, anyway, for your effort!

Comment: It's ok for a website, run `express` server with node for example. (website/app is the same)